# THE simplest/easiest possible way to remote into an Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm going to set up a new Ubuntu install for my dad. I know there will be times he'll be asking for help, so I need a way to remote into that box (a free solution). What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu ships with remote desktop but it is off by default. Search for "desktop" in dash and it will show "desktop sharing". Your dad needs to check the top choice (and do make him set a password).

[image]

It is the easiest method for your dad. Your side needs installation but that is not to difficult (and you probably are already familiar with it). You need to have open-ssh server installed on your machine.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And all you then need is his IP and his password to take over his machine.

---

There are other choices that are web only like logmein or teamviewer but remote desktop is already available.

Comment: What is typically involved in getting through his router's firewall? I would have thought that setting up the firewall to allow the ports through would be necessary and a nuisance.

Comment: Could I ask what you do with the IP address and password?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly for easy adhoc support to friends and family [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) is a great "free" as in beer option.  No need to setup port forwards or bounce off servers to get it going.  They have .deb packages available for download from their site.  I find that the x86 multiarch is most compatible across most new Ubuntu releases.

Your dad just has to launch it and tell you the 9 digit ID, you then punch that in at your end and the connection is setup through teamviewers servers.  You can also setup unattended access so you can remote in without the need for your dad to do anything.

Comment: Not too hip on the Teamviewer idea! Trying to install it (even 64-bit) wants to install a bunch of i386 architecture junk. Also it uses Wine.

Comment: I use it day in day out for work so I guess I'm biased. I'm cool with the i386 library's as I have plenty of disk space.  Its worth it for helping non techies it install through the software centre one click to launch and your on.